# Requesting specific nodes with TORQUE qsub?

Tags: torque

There's a cluster with TORQUE qsub installed. I want to send a job, but I want to make sure that it runs on one of a specific set of nodes.

Is it possible to request a list of possible nodes in `qsub`, so that the job is sent to one of the nodes in the requested set, never to a node outside the set?

Comment: See this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392786/how-to-submit-a-job-to-a-specific-node-in-pbs

Comment: @slm Yes, that allows you to request one specific node. However, that's not enough for me. I want to specify a *set* of possible nodes, such that my job goes to one or several nodes *from that set*. I plan to send many jobs (array request), so specifying a single node is not enough for me.